# How would I create a wish list?

Tags: php

I'm making a website which displays a big list of items, similar to how eBay lists items.  For each item there is a button that allows you to save it to your "wish list," and a link that brings you to a page that lists all the items on your wishlist.

How would I go about implementing this?  I am currently using Javascript cookies and passing the values in the URL for PHP to pick up and display the wish-listed items.  It feels like there must be an easier/better way to do this though.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you just use one cookie with the list of ID's?  You can set/update the cookie from JS; when your next PHP is called, you can read the cookie from PHP.

Comment: i was going down this route, but have to use a new cookie for each id saved so that you can also remove id's from the saved list. also can php read a cookie set by javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to store the wish list is the database only. You can do that by some ajax.

Or if you dont want to store in database then store it in session. I personally feels that the session will be the best thing.

Comment: ah, that kind of anwsers it! i need use a SESSION in the ajax. thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the user wants their wish list to last longer than the browser closing.  I would.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with `I was using javascript cookies, passing the values in the url`, but unless you want to save the wish-list to Db, a cookie will be a good way to go.

Another way would be to execute an ajax-request to the server when you add something to the list, having the server-side code saving the item for you in a session. Then session could then be read when you want to display the list.

Also, HTML5 gives you [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). Maybe too limited browser support for you, but worth checking out.

Comment: ah, that kind of anwsers it! i need use a SESSION in the ajax. thanks

Comment: @Lan Well sort of, JavaScript cannot access a session like it can with a cookie, as the session live in the memory of the server. You will have to call a server-side PHP/ASP.NET (or whatever you use) file, that can access the session and add stuff to it. You will then have to call that file through Ajax to add stuff.